# MySQL 8.0.15 connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am completely new to PHP/MySQL and am using My SQL 8.0.15 and trying to learn PHP and MySQL and did the following user entry:

```
create user if not exists 'mike@localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'easysteps';

grant select, insert, update on site_db to 'mike@localhost';
```

---

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","mike","easysteps","site_db");
```

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\conxyz.php on line 2

Comment: what mysqli_connect arguments are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Open you my.ini and change like this

> default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
>
> See:
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin

Comment: This only affects users not created with an explicit plug-in, which the OP has specified. As such this isn't an answer.

Comment: PHP use old way to connect MySQL (use password not encrypt). Why is my answer  wrong?

Comment: The question explicitly created the user with 'mysql_native_password'. The server shouldn't be asking for caching_sha2_password for this user regardless of the `default_authentication_plugin` setting. I assume the code is connecting to a different host/user or the `create  user` / `grant` returned an error that was ignored.